# How to find "hits" source in test coverage Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, code-coverage

I am currently unit testing an Android application (using Android Studio), with interest for the code coverage.

I found out it is possible for every line of code to know its number of "hits" (i.e. the number of time the line was executed in launched tests).

But is there a way to find out which test resulted in this hit ?

Thanks.